# How to set context with React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs

With [`cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), one can set new props like:

```
React.cloneElement(node, { ...props });
```

Is there a way to set `context` also? Or is the only way to pass context to wrap it in a React component, and set `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` on this container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since react 0.14 context is based on the parent, so cloning a component doesn't clone context, because the context is not part of the component. This official [answer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4008#issuecomment-109104520) explains that change.

In addition to the parent configuration (childContextTypes and getChildContext), your component should also include `contextTypes` to use context.